# Change column name in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

How to change the column name in SQL Server 2014 using query?

Comment: Please always google before asking question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For this you can use this query

```
USE DATABASE;  
GO  
EXEC sp_rename 'TABLE.COLUMN_NAME', 'COLUMN_NEW_NAME', 'COLUMN';  
GO
```

You will have to replace `DATABASE`,`TABLE`,`COLUMN_NAME` and `COLUMN_NEW_NAME` with your data

Comment: @ChrisM yes his query is for Oracle SQL, I didn't comment on his answer cause i don't have enough rep :)
PS: ty for the answer format edit

Comment: I thought it was as well.